# mod_rewrite url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

**What I am trying to do:**

Change

```
www.mysitename.com/pages/about
```

to

```
www.mysitename.com/about
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1
```

but when I go onto my website and click the about section, the url is still www.**.com/pages/about. htaccess is enabled on my server, so that's not the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to change it *where*, exactly? `mod_rewrite` only modifies the URL right before it is interpreted by the web server. It doesn't (and can't possibly) change what's in your browser's address bar.

Comment: Okay -- I think I completely misinterpreted what mod rewrite does, then. I was under the impression that it "prettifies the url" -- so instead of an ugly .com/pages/about, the pages is taken out to .com/about; if mod_rewrite isn't the correct way to do this, what would you suggest? Thank you so much.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: Just to confirm: the the mod rewrite rule DOESN'T (and can't possibly) change what's in the browser's address bar, right? So it wouldn't make the url from .com/pages/about to .com/about? (thank you for the links, but I couldn't find what I wanted in the sources)

Comment: Right, it cannot do that. If that's what you want, you should consider a simple `header('Location: ...')` *redirect*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# change URL in browser from /pages/about to /about
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+pages/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# internally forward /about to /pages/about
RewriteRule ^((?!pages/).+)$ pages/$1 [L,NC]
```